# Excel VBA: Application.Run Error 1004: Cannot find file despite it being in same folder and my trying it with the full path

Tags: vba, excel

Using VBA in one workbook, I'm trying to run a macro in another workbook using `Application.Run "'MyFile v0.1.xls'!ABCMacro"`. 
From reading, I believe the syntax is correct (included single quotation marks etc) but I get a `1004 run-time error` that states (most times) `Method 'Run' of object '_Application' failed` but on other occasions has stated (I couldn't get the 1004 message to show this right now so the following is just from memory) `Cannot find the file. Has it been moved or deleted?`

The target workbook and the current one are in the same directory (and I cut and paste the names to avoid typos). I have also tried `Application.Run` using the full path back to `C:\\` but with the same result.

Much has been written around this issue but none of the answers found (so far after two hours of looking and testing) actually solve the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
BJA

Comment: 1) try to remove extension: `Application.Run "'MyFile v0.1'!ABCMacro"` 2) check whether you workbook opened exactly in this instance of `Application`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to happen on my system too, and after playing around with security settings and code location, I can't find what the problem is...

However, opening the file, running the macro, and closing the file makes it work fine.

Try :

```
Set wbToClose = Workbooks.Open("C:\yourPath\yourFile.xlsm")
Application.Run ("yourFile.xlsm!'yourFunction'")
wbToClose.Close False
```